# OutOfMemory error when writing to s3a through EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

Getting an OutOfMemory error for the following PySpark code: (fails after a certain number of rows are written. This does not happen if I attempt to write to the hadoop filesystem instead of using s3a, so I think I've narrowed it down to the problem being s3a. ) - end goal to write to s3a.
Was wondering if there was an optimal s3a configuration where I will not run out of memory for extremely large tables.

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM my_big_table")
df.repartition(1).write.option("header", "true").csv("s3a://mycsvlocation/folder/")
```

my s3a configurations (emr default) :

```
('fs.s3a.attempts.maximum', '10')
('fs.s3a.buffer.dir', '${hadoop.tmp.dir}/s3a')
('fs.s3a.connection.establish.timeout', '5000')
('fs.s3a.connection.maximum', '15')
('fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled', 'true')
('fs.s3a.connection.timeout', '50000')
('fs.s3a.fast.buffer.size', '1048576')
('fs.s3a.fast.upload', 'true')
('fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')
('fs.s3a.max.total.tasks', '1000')
('fs.s3a.multipart.purge', 'false')
('fs.s3a.multipart.purge.age', '86400')
('fs.s3a.multipart.size', '104857600')
('fs.s3a.multipart.threshold', '2147483647')
('fs.s3a.paging.maximum', '5000')
('fs.s3a.threads.core', '15')
('fs.s3a.threads.keepalivetime', '60')
('fs.s3a.threads.max', '256')
('mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version', '2')
('spark.authenticate', 'true')
('spark.network.crypto.enabled', 'true')
('spark.network.crypto.saslFallback', 'true')
('spark.speculation', 'false')
```

base of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.hugeCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:123)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:117)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFastOutputStream.write(S3AFastOutputStream.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:60)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.input.WriterCharAppender.writeCharsAndReset(WriterCharAppender.java:152)
        at com.univocity.parsers.common.AbstractWriter.writeRow(AbstractWriter.java:808)
        ... 16 more
```

Comment: My guess would would be it's because of the `repartition(1)` since all load goes into one worker. Can you try without the `repartition` and confirm it's working or not? Also if you are able to write in hdfs you can use `s3distcp` to copy from `hdfs` to `s3`.

Comment: spark is much better with multiple files not single.

Comment: EMR doesn’t support `S3A`. Use `S3`. [Aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html) Yes you can use it, but there are lot of problems may arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the default s3a upload does not support uploading of a singular large file greater than 2GB or 2147483647 bytes.

```
('fs.s3a.multipart.threshold', '2147483647')
```

My EMR version is older than the more recent ones so the multipart.threshold parameter is only an integer, thus the limit is 2147483647 bytes, for a single "part" or file. The more recent versions use long instead of int and can support a larger single file size limit.

I'll be using a work around write the file to local hdfs then moving it to s3 via a separate java program.